# Acumatica scheduling an action

Tags: acumatica, schedule

I am trying to create a routine to import orders from our EDI service into Acumatica.  I have created a skeleton action:

```
public PXAction<EDOrderReviewFilter> GetOrders;
    [PXProcessButton()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Get Orders")]
    protected virtual void getOrders()
    {
        EDOrderReview graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<EDOrderReview>();
        graph.Filter.Current.ReviewType = "A";
        throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, false, "Review");
    }
```

I can finish the code to retrieve the orders and insert the sales orders, but I cannot get this to schedule. The order review graph display would not be included in the automated retrieval.  The schedule appears to only allow scheduling of Process All even though the documentation says it should be a picklist of the actions in the graph.  Can anyone help?  Is there a better way to schedule the order retrieval?  The current thought is to check every 15 minutes and import all new orders.

=============New information============================================

I am having trouble now making the calling graph show the spinning timer while orders are being retrieved.  In the code below the EDGetOrders.cs is the new processing page that simply retrieves the orders.  This will eventually be hidden and scheduled.  EDOrderReview.cs is the original graph that allows review and adjustment of imported orders where I would like to have a button that will initiate an order retrieve and show some feedback that the process is running and then show some indication that it is finished. Using the PressButton method processes the retrieve synchronously and then the screen refreshes via the last three lines.  The LongOperation method starts the process asynchronously and immediately redraws the screen.  Am I using the LongOperation correctly?

```
// EDGetOrders.cs  Separate graph to simply retrieve the orders
    // Action to retrieve orders
    public PXAction<EDGetOrderFilter> GetOrders;
    [PXProcessButton()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "")]
    protected virtual void getOrders()
    {
        getEDIOrders();
    }
    // This function performs all the work and works fine
    public void getEDIOrders()
    {
        ...
    }
    // This function is called on Process All and works fine and shows the spinning timer
    public void ProcessOrder(List<EDIGetOrder> list, string type)
    {
        SOOrderEntry soOrderGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
        bool errorOccured = false;
        string statusText = "";
        foreach (EDIGetOrder ediOrder in list)
        {
            PXProcessing<EDIGetOrder>.SetCurrentItem(ediOrder);
            getOrders();
            statusText = "Orders Retrieved";
        }
        if (errorOccured)
            throw new PXOperationCompletedWithErrorException(statusText);
        else
            throw new PXOperationCompletedException(statusText);
```

## }

```
//EDOrderReview.cs Original graph I want to call getOrders from and show the spinning timer
    //Action to create button
    public PXAction<EDOrderReviewFilter> GetOrders;
    [PXProcessButton()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Get Orders")]
    protected virtual void getOrders()
    {
        EDGetOrders getOrders = PXGraph.CreateInstance<EDGetOrders>();
        //getOrders.GetOrders.PressButton();
        PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate () { goGetOrders(); });
        //Redraw the screen with the new orders
        EDOrderReview graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<EDOrderReview>();
        graph.Filter.Current.ReviewType = "A";
        throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, false, "Review");
    }

    public static void goGetOrders()
    {
        EDGetOrders getOrders = PXGraph.CreateInstance<EDGetOrders>();
        getOrders.getEDIOrders();
    }
```

Comment: If you setup a processing page this can be scheduled by default, however you need to have something to "process". So if you are looking to schedule a process in Acumatica to simply run every 15 minutes then I would set the schedule process to process some type of setup record as its needs something and then go get your orders in that process. Does this help? A processing page example being Release IN documents. Please clarify if I am way off the question.

Comment: I have a process page that I control the Process visibility based on conditions of the filter criteria variables.  Process All is always invisible as it is not needed for this page.  The process page selects orders based on exception types (duplicate, different price, missing inventory item, missing customer location) and then allows orders to be held, canceled, or released.  The decision was to only allow process and not process all to avoid mistakes.  I was trying to add this new action to this page but it does not show as available in the scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current documentation doesn't match with the actual behavior of the Automation Schedules screen. In reality, the Action Name field always stays disabled and can only show the Process All option. Hopefully, this explains why it won't be possible to schedule order retrieval from your current processing page.

An alternative solution would be to create a stand-alone processing screen just to retrieve orders from external EDI service, which you can schedule to run the Process All action every 15 minutes. You can hide this new processing screen from users by placing it in the Hidden folder of the SiteMap.

For sure, you can still keep the Get Orders button on your current processing screen and, if you implement your method to retrieve orders from external EDI service as static, it should be possible to invoke the same method from both your current and new processing screens.

**Update to answer the New Information section:**

You should throw PXRedirectRequiredException to show EDOrderReview  ***after*** the GetEDIOrders operation is over:

```
public PXAction<EDOrderReviewFilter> GetOrders;
[PXProcessButton()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Get Orders")]
protected virtual void getOrders()
{
    EDGetOrders getOrders = PXGraph.CreateInstance<EDGetOrders>();
    //getOrders.GetOrders.PressButton();
    PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate () 
    { 
        goGetOrders(); 

        //Redraw the screen with the new orders
        EDOrderReview graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<EDOrderReview>();
        graph.Filter.Current.ReviewType = "A";
        throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, false, "Review");
    });
}

public static void goGetOrders()
{
    EDGetOrders getOrders = PXGraph.CreateInstance<EDGetOrders>();
    getOrders.getEDIOrders();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ruslan.  I appreciate your time on this.  One last question.  If this processing screen only uses Process and never uses Process All could I override Process All to a different method in the graph?  Normally, Process All is invisible as the screen is designed to always require individual lines checked to specify rows to operate on.  If I am correct, Process and Process All will execute the same routine just with a different set of rows.  Can I detect that Process All was clicked and do the order import instead of the normal process routine?  I can rename Process All.

Comment: It's not possible to detect which of the 2 buttons (Process or Process All)  were pressed once process delegate gets executed by a standard PXProcessing or PXProcessingJoin data view. It's possible though to inherit from one of those 2 classes and override the ProcessAll method `[PXProcessButton] [PXUIField(DisplayName = ActionsMessages.ProcessAll, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)] protected virtual IEnumerable ProcessAll(PXAdapter adapter) { ... }` Just make sure to preserve the attributes on an overridden method, if you decide to take that route.

Comment: Is there an example of this in the system or one of the training guides?  I don't feel comfortable trying this without a little more information.  If not, I will go the route of another process screen.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such example anywhere... To be honest, this is the first time I ever heard about this design (when Process and Process All buttons launch different processes) and won't recommend doing something that is quite opposite to how any other processing screen works in Acumatica - might result in more confusion from users than benefit in terms of the UX.

Comment: The retrieve action is working and I am trying to make ProcessAll run process. The grid on this process screen is a virtual DAC so I added one row and added logic to the process to call the import routine and throw a completed exception at the end, but it doesn't seem to call the routine correctly.  I add the row and call the delegate just like the other actions.  Is there anything else I need to do for ProcessAll vs. Process?  I think I am going to go the route of an independent process page.  How do I call the process from the button on my original page?

Comment: @JerryWelliver, there is nothing special you should do for Process All vs Process. I think it will be best if you start a new thread and include some of your code to show what specific issue/question is.

Comment: Success!  The separate process page works fine. I was also able to call the action original page using the PressButton() method on the action.  It ironically shows as a schedulable action on the original page(I assume this is because I am calling a "ProcessAll" action). One thing left that I would like to do is show a busy icon or mouse pointer while the called process is running. The timer does not show. I chang the display when it is done, but is there some way to suspend the page until it completes, similar to a modal dialog?  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Currently, the framework does not provide a way to change mouse pointer. There is no "busy icon" on your separate process page because when the PressButton() method is called on the ProcessAll action, the ProcessAll action starts a separate background thread to execute the processing delegate. The easiest way to show "busy icon" on a separate processing page is by executing same method (ideally a static one), that is used on the original page, with the PXLongOperation.StartOperation() method, instead of calling the ProcessAll action.

Comment: Ruslan, see the updates to the original post above and let me know if I can accomplish this.  Again, you have been an enormous help with this!

Comment: Jerry, that was very close. Please check my updated answer above.